# What to return to browser if DNS lookup failed?

Tags: dns, http-status-codes

*Disclaimer:* not sure if this is SO material. If not, please move it to the appropriate place.

I'm trying to build a web proxy, and I'm unsure what to return to the browser, if the DNS lookup failed (ie. if the domain does not exist). Is there a HTTP status code for this? I tried looking in the Network tab in Chrome, but there's no response for a failed DNS lookup.

Comment: Just to be clear; you mean that your proxy is doing all the name resolution, not the client?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Not sure about what the client does, but I need an IP to connect to, so I do a lookup to get the IP, in order to connect the socket to it.

Comment: there wouldn't be an http code for it, since by definition an HTTP request couldn't be done in the first place is the server's IP couldn't be resolved. probably the easiest-to-use-instead would be 404 - "not found"

Comment: Thought of that, but then the browsers couldn't handle this in their own way. I would like each browser to show it's own "this page cannot be displayed" page, instead of me returning a 404 page. Is that possible?

Comment: Most I have seen return `502 Bad Gateway` or `504 Gateway Timeout`.

Comment: Did a little more digging and thinking and @MarcB, you're right. Could you please post the comment as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There wouldn't be an HTTP code for it, since by definition an HTTP request couldn't be done in the first place is the server's IP couldn't be resolved. Probably the easiest-to-use-instead would be 404 - "not found" or 404.1 - "site not found" if you have IIS 7.0+.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing @Dark Falcon's comment and mysterious withdrawal from the question

"Most I have seen return 502 Bad Gateway or 504 Gateway Timeout"